# Get the Image URLs from Top.Images object

Tags: javascript

I'm working with a website that generates lots of images that I want to save to disk. To do so I need to get a list of URLs containing all the images.

[image: ChromeImageStorage]

The above picture was taking from the Application tab of Google Chrome's debugging tools. Each of the 'green' files is a 'stored image' or rather, a referenced image URL.

How can I access this list from JavaScript console?

---

If it is not possible to access this folder/object from javascript, would it be possible to:

1. Query some database on disk that might contain the files.
2. Access the files via the Internet Explorer ActiveX Object?

Comment: I really don't understand exactly what do you want. Correct me if i'm wrong. You want to get a list of image urls? and from your website or from another website?

Comment: @AhmedCommando "You want to get a list of image urls?" basically yes, however the images loaded aren't within the HTML. This is from a website someone else has created.

Answer (score 1):

```
var resources = window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource");
resources.forEach(function (resource) {
    console.log(resource.name);
});
```

The above will list all of the files specified.

Answer (score 1):

```
var resources = window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource");
resources.forEach(function (resource) {
    if (resource.name.indexOf(".png") > -1 || resource.name.indexOf(".jpg")> -1)
    console.log(resource.name);
});
```

As @Sancarn said with my extras line this function will writes all the images that have .png or .jpg as an extension. try it and let me know.

Comment: That's even better! Thanks!